# Local administration privileges to develop spfx solutions?

Tags: spfx

Can you setup and develop spfx solution without local administration privileges?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. You need local admin rights atleast once for environment setup.

The basic environment setup requires that you install the NodeJS and a code editor like VS Code or Atom. Also, you need to install a developer certificate as well to test/preview the code in local workbench.

All this would require admin privileges.

Having said that, once the environment is ready, i.e, the admin has performed these tasks for you, those privileges wont be necessary. You can create the spfx solution and ship them to sharepoint without need of local admin privileges.

Reference - [Setup SPFx dev environment](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment)

Comment: hey @langer, could you please mark it as answer if it helped you ? Its just a checkmark below the upvote button.